# PBY-5A exhaust modification?

Tags: engine-design, pby-catalina

What is the function of these “tubes” that cover the outboard exhaust stacks on some PBY-5A and PBY-6A aircraft?

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: [German Wiki](https://de.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Consolidated_PBY) says the exhaust gases were used to de-ice the wings. Could it have something to do with that?

Comment: I'm going with a cabin heating system for northern operations.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks for the suggestions in the comments.

Using the term “heat exchanger” I was able to find an Aircraft Modelling forum that gave the answer I was looking for.

[Interpreting wartime photography: Catalina in Ceylon](https://www.britmodeller.com/forums/index.php?/topic/235040391-interpreting-wartime-photography-catalina-in-ceylon/)

It is indeed a heat exchanger system for leading edge anti-icing. The tail appears to have a separate anti-ice system that burns fuel for heat. This thermal anti-icing was introduced on late model PBY-5A. It probably was an optional system.

[image]

Comment: On some jets with heated LE, usually hard LE non-slatted ones, the LEs are heated above the boiling point, 220F or so, by high temp bleed.  They are "evaporative" systems that are like spitting on a steam iron, and the idea is to prevent runback ice forming behind the leading edges.  If you have slats, you can tolerate runback ice and the system can run much cooler, around 140-160F.

Comment: Apparently the German Wiki pointed in the right direction :-). It also says that the Catalina was the first plane to use such an exhaust operated heating for anti-icing (_"In addition, their exhaust fumes served for the first time the deicing of the wing."_ (Google translated)).